# Is $e^{-i\omega t}$ oscillating or decaying?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I know $e^{i\omega t}$ is a trial solution used for solving harmonic oscillator equations it makes sense but why $e^{-i\omega t}$?

Comment: *Is $e^{-i\omega t}$ oscillating or decaying?* Doesn’t [Euler’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) make clear whether it oscillates or decays?

Answer (score 1):

The trial solution for a homogeneous linear ODE with constant coefficients is $x(t) = A \,{\rm e}^{\lambda \, t}$.  By plugging that into your equation, you will find constraints on $\lambda$ such that the trial solution is actually a solution.  And from that you can construct the general solution to the ODE.

For the harmonic oscillator:
$$
F_{Sx} = m a_x \quad \rightarrow \quad -k x = m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} \quad \rightarrow \quad  \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = -\omega^2 x \quad \quad (\omega^2:= k/m)
$$
plugging in the trial solution yields:
$$
\lambda^2 A \, {\rm e}^{\lambda \, t} = -\omega^2 A\, {\rm e}^{\lambda \, t}  \quad \rightarrow \quad \lambda = \sqrt{- \omega ^2} = \pm i \omega\,.
$$
So our trial solution works, and it produces the two necessary independent solutions to construct the general solution to a second-order ODE:
$$
x(t) = a {\rm e}^{+ i \omega t} + b {\rm e}^{- i \omega t}\,.
$$
The constants $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ are then fixed by initial conditions and the physical requirement that your solution for $x(t)$ is real. Using Euler's formula, ${\rm e}^{i \phi} = \cos \phi + i \sin \phi$, we can write:
$$
x(t)= (a + b) \cos(\omega t) +  i (a - b)\sin (\omega t)
$$
which shows that the solution is *oscillatory*, and that we must require:
$$
{\rm Re}(b) = {\rm Re}(a) \quad \text{and} \quad {\rm Im}(b) = - {\rm Im}(a)
$$
to obtain a real solution.  In other words $b = a^*$.